# How to get apex:outputLink to work in Lightning Desktop correctly using target='parent'?

Tags: visualforce-component, lightning-experience, lightning

In Lightning Desktop we have come across an issue when using `apex:outputLink` that has a target of "_parent".  The links will not work in Explorer or Firefox.  The link works fine in Chrome.

The following JavaScript error appears in Firefox and Explorer

> 'SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete
>   the operation due to error 00002ee2. File: one.app

Simple Source code to reproduce

```
<apex:page >
This is Page one
     <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value="/apex/PROTOTYPE_page_two">
          <div>
               <strong>Link to Page two</strong>
          </div>
     </apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Note : I attached the Visualforce page (page_one) through the page layout.

I can do a JavaScript work around using the solution outlined on [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages). However I don't want to have to go and change all my apex:outputLinks to use a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Change the target to _Self and give a try.